# What does tail -0a do?

Tags: man, tail

In the [documentation](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/tutorials/getting-started-with-logstash) for logstash, they mention the command `tail -0a`

I have never heard of the -a flag and I can't find any information on google, tail --help or the man pages.

What is the difference between `tail -0a foo.bar` and `tail foo.bar`

**Update**

After testing this further, I wonder if it is a typo. Neither command works on my mac.

```
[root@interactive adaptive]# tail -0a /var/log/messages
tail: option used in invalid context -- 0


[root@interactive adaptive]# tail -a0 /var/log/messages
tail: invalid option -- 'a'
```

Comment: Came here because this site mentioned "tail -0a": http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/tutorials/getting-started-with-logstash

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tail -0` is a historical, deprecated way of writing `tail -n 0`, i.e. print the last 0 lines of the file. (So `tail -0` doesn't produce any output.)

I don't know of any `tail` implementation that has a `-a` option. From context, it looks like `-f` was meant. `tail -f` makes `tail` keep the file open when it reaches the end, and keep watching forever in case some other program appends more data at the end of the file, and prints this appended data as it comes. So `tail -0f` starts at the current end of the file, and prints any data that is subsequently appended to the file.

Comment: @Giles So what will happen if `tail -f -n 0` combination is used? Suppose that the file is growing continuously.

Comment: @Geek It starts at the current end of the file, and prints any data that is subsequently appended to the file.

Comment: @Giles one more follow up question. So if I had used `tail -n 5 -f file` then as the file grows it always shows the last 5 lines right? Then going by that analogy `tail -n 0 -f file` should never output anything at all even if the files grows after starting the tail command. What am I missing?

Comment: @Geek No. With `tail -n 5 -f`, first the last 5 lines are displayed, then everything that's appended to the file. `tail` is not a viewer that refreshes to show the last N lines of the file, it's a filter that removes the beginning of the file. Once it's printed something out, it can't take it back.

Answer (score 2):

The `-0` means 0 lines, in other words, don't print any existing stuff.

None of the tail man pages mention a `-a` option.  Perhaps they meant `-f` or `-F`, which would print any new contents written after `tail` started.

References:

- [Mac OS X tail man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tail.1.html)
- [FreeBSD tail man page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tail&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+10.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html)
- [GNU tail info docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tail-invocation.html#tail-invocation)
- [Solaris tail man page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29030/tail-1.html#scrolltoc)